# How to drop this index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

It's created this way:

```
create table listings(
    id integer unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    accountId  integer unsigned default null,
    title varchar(300) not null,
    country integer unsigned,
    region integer unsigned,
    type integer unsigned,
    price integer,
    unit varchar(20) not null,
    priceUSD decimal(12,2),
    bedrooms integer unsigned,
    thumbnail varchar(100) default null,
    keywords text,
    created datetime,
    deleted boolean default 0,
    fulltext index (keywords),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) engine=MyISAM;
```

How to drop that fulltext index which has no name?

What if the un-named index is:`fulltext index (title ,keywords)`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run this command in the `mysql` client:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE listings;
```

It will show you the DDL for the table, including the *system-assigned name* for the index.

Comment: Use your `test` database and create a new, empty table with a fulltext index, just so you can observe how `show create table` shows the system-assigned names for indexes and constraints.

Answer (score 94):

```
ALTER TABLE listings DROP INDEX keywords;
```

Answer (score 29):

`ALTER TABLE {your_table_name} DROP INDEX {your_index_name}`

OR

`DROP INDEX {your_index_name} ON {your_tbl_name}`

Answer (score 3):

You can also get table index information using [SHOW INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-index.html) syntax.

```sql
SHOW INDEX FROM listings;
```

Also, when you don't provide a name for the index, MySQL will automatically provide a name for the index based on the column(s) being indexed.

For `fulltext index (keywords)`, MySQL will most likely name the index `keywords`.

For `fulltext index (title ,keywords)`, MySQL will most likely name the index `title`.

I say "most likely" because if there is already an index named `keywords` or `title`, MySQL will name it something else.